# Application Crashes Immediately after adding Apache POI as External Libraries

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I'm writing an application that utilizes Apache poi as external libraries so that I am able to generate excel files using data generated on the app. However, after adding the apache jars to my lib folder and implementing them on my app build.gradle, I receive various DexArchiveBuilderExceptions.

I've attempted to invalidate my caches and restart, as well as set my project to source compatibility Java_1_8; however, I still receive the same errors.

```java
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.statstopwatch"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/poi-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-examples-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-excelant-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-scratchpad-4.1.0.jar')
}
```

[image]
I added these external libraries by pasting them into the libs folder and adding them as libraries, is this perhaps the cause of the error?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to raise your `minSdkVersion` to 26, as those libraries are using things from Java 8 that are only available on Android 8.0 and higher.

Or, find a version of those libraries that either are older or are designed for Android, that might allow you to keep your current `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: Awesome, this solution worked for me. Assuming that I use the current libraries, does raising the minimum sdk vastly restrict the usage of the application on most Android devices or are most around sdk version 26?

Comment: @ousalia: As of early May, Android 8.0 and higher represent about 40% of all Android devices using the Play Store: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/ . That percentage will vary by country and other characteristics, but the overall dashboard is a good "rule of thumb" for how widespread a version is.